# installing nwrfcsdk library for PHP

Tags: php, saprfc

I made some RFC functions on SAP, to be able to access to them via Web. I need to install the SAP nwrfcsdk library into my server.

Does anyone knows a step by step guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to identify your OS and then download it from SAP (service.sap.com), may be you will need the SAPCAR utility (download fom SAP also) for decompressing the nwsaprfc component in your machine. Then, download the last version of PHP library from http://www.piersharding.com/download/php/sapnwrfc/

Hope it helps.

Comment: all ready solved but thanks that was the answer!!